# Return instance by value from a method stack compilation

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, return-value, most-vexing-parse

Can you explain why this won't compile:

(this is the error:

```
../Man.cpp:33:9: error: conversion from ‘Man (*)()’ to non-scalar type ‘Man’ requested)
```

Code:

```
Man goo(){
  Man m();
  return m;
}
```

but this does:

```
Man goo(){
    return Man();
}
```

Comment: Next time please *read* the information about how to ask a question and the instructions on formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Man m();
```

This means "somewhere else in the program, I will define a function named `m` that takes no arguments and returns a `Man`". Yes, even when you write it inside another function.

```
Man m;
```

This means "`m` is a variable of type `Man`". Since `Man` is a class type, the default constructor will be called and no parentheses are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want those parentheses in your first example:

```
Man goo(){
  Man m;
  return m;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need () in the first case. The default constructor is called implicitly.

```
Man goo(){
    Man m;
    return m; 
}
```

In the second case you are calling the constructor.